# Is there a way where I can redirect the page to a record after insert trigger without using visualforce aura or lwc?

Tags: apex, trigger, redirect, merge

All I want to do is merge leads after the insertion of one lead(if found duplicate).
merging is working correctly but I want it to redirect to the merged lead record after merging. Is there a way we can do it without using vf page or aura because I am not using any of them.

Answer (score 0):

No. Apex cannot perform any kind of redirect directly from a trigger. I would consider merging the other way around; merge the existing lead into the new lead. This should have the same general effect without any extra work.

Comment: thank you for your response. unfortunately, the flow for this functionality doesn't work like that. I need to create a new lead and then check if it is similar and then merge it.

Comment: @YatharthSharma You may want to share some code. As it is, you have an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What you're trying to do is impossible, but there may very well be a workaround or alternative solution. For example, [FindDuplicates](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Datacloud_FindDuplicates.htm) allows you to find duplicates without inserting a record.

Comment: thank for your response as it turns out Find duplicate is just what I was looking for

Comment: @YatharthSharma Great, glad I could help!